# How to emulate mouse click in Cocoa application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I need to send mouse click to my `NSView`. Documentation says about `NSEvent +mouseEventWithType:location:modifierFlags:timestamp:windowNumber:context:eventNumber:clickCount:pressure:` function. But I can't found info how to exactly use this. Which values of `timestamp`, `eventNumber` and `clickNumber` should be used? Also no type for *click* event. There are types for mouse down and mouse up events. Whether I send both them in one moment? Or I must do some delay? Currently I try to use such code.

```c
// self.label is NSTextField
[self.label setAllowsEditingTextAttributes: YES];
[self.label setSelectable: YES];

NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Google"];
[str addAttribute: NSLinkAttributeName value: @"http://www.google.com" range: NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
[self.label setAttributedStringValue:str];

NSEvent *mouseEvent;
mouseEvent = [NSEvent mouseEventWithType:NSLeftMouseDown
                                location:NSMakePoint(0., 0.)
                           modifierFlags:0
                               timestamp:0
                            windowNumber:0
                                 context:nil
                             eventNumber:0
                              clickCount:1
                                pressure:1.];
[self.label mouseDown:mouseEvent];

mouseEvent = [NSEvent mouseEventWithType:NSLeftMouseUp
                                location:NSMakePoint(0., 0.)
                           modifierFlags:0
                               timestamp:0
                            windowNumber:0
                                 context:nil
                             eventNumber:0
                              clickCount:1
                                pressure:1.];

[self.label mouseUp:mouseEvent];
```

Seems it works. But after such click when I move mouse pointer to label mouse pointer is not showing as hand (to open url). My initital problem url is not showing in `NSTextField` as url. It looks as regular text. After click on any place in label (not link) text becames highlighted. So I want to do programmatically click after `NSWindow` showing to apply click workaround.

P.S. Actually initial questiong with URL's in `NSTextField` solved. I rewrite my code to use `NSTextView` instead of `NSTextField`. It fully worked as expected but requires more customization. Also IB automatically created `NSScrollView` for `NSTextView`. Anyway question about correct creating `NSEvent` and sending is still actual.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code to create a fake event to pop up a context menu relative to a WKWebView position I send via Javascript. Anyway it should be universal to be used for other purposes as well:

```c
NSPoint clickPoint = NSMakePoint(x, y);
NSEvent * evt = [NSEvent mouseEventWithType:NSEventTypeLeftMouseUp 
                                   location:[view convertPoint:clickPoint toView:nil]
                              modifierFlags:0
                                  timestamp:0
                               windowNumber:view.window.windowNumber 
                                    context:nil
                                eventNumber:0
                                 clickCount:1
                                   pressure:1.];
```

Answer (score 0):

To change mouse pointer you can write a customized text field class, and override "resetCursorRects"

you can refer link: [Can't change the mouse cursor of a NSTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079531/cant-change-the-mouse-cursor-of-a-nstextfield)

Comment: Seems it can be used for case when whole content in NSTextField is hyperlink. But what with case when only part of text is hyperlink?

Comment: looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752772/how-to-trigger-a-mousedownnsevent-programmatically-without-using-the-mouse

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to mouse click it. Making it the first responder is enough. But that is fragile. There are a lot topics about that original problem [NSTextField with URL-style format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058699/nstextfield-with-url-style-format)

I had the same problem and in the end, I used a NSTextView instead of the NSTextField.